# Are multiple PGCE required to teach multiple subjects in the UK?

Tags: teaching, undergraduate, job, united-kingdom, education

I'm currently finishing the 3rd year of my Computer Science course at University. My expected classification is Second-class honours, upper division (2:1). After I finish this course, I'd like to go ahead and study further for a Post Graduate Certificate in Education (PGCE) and become a teacher.

The question I have, is how do people / teachers approach teaching multiple subjects? Do they do a PGCE in the subject they've gained a degree in and then move on to study teaching another subject after they have their teaching capabilities? Or do they do 2 PGCEs at the same time?

The reason I'm asking this question is because I want to become an ICT & Computing teacher, but also a P.E. teacher on the side and I'm unsure of which path to take (or which path I must take?)

It's worth noting that my interest for P.E. has purely been from a personal  experience as I've become keen of the gym and realised the importance of staying fit and healthy since University. I don't have a GCSE (or any equivalent qualification) in P.E. as it's something I never liked when I was younger.

Any advice from fellow academics would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JoelMurphy-I think that you need not have multiple PGCE certificates for teaching more than one subjects,However you may require a CIDE (Certificate in Interdisciplinary Education),OK?

Comment: Have a look on the Get in to Teaching website (https://getintoteaching.education.gov.uk/). From there you can be put in contact with an advisor to help you through the system.

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon for teachers to teach related subjects, but computing and physical education is a bit of a stretch.

You would not need a second PGCE, but it would probably be in your favour to get some kind of professional experience or some kind of qualification that displays your dedication to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You just do one PGCE and (in the case of secondary education) you pick one subject - I expect the best idea is to train in the subject which you are most experienced in because the main thrust of the PGCE is learning to teach so you want to have command of your subject knowledge; you don't need to be worrying about being "found out".

The equation is about how desperate the school is, especially in shortage subjects like maths, physics, computer science.  I had a computer science degree but trained as a maths teacher and then I was able to offer computer science teaching as well once I was established as a maths teacher.  I had colleagues who taught (as recently as this year just finished) across all sorts of faculties, so you probably can do what you say you want to do.  You'll have to look out for opportunities to gain PE experience, e.g. by running an after school cricket club or something - you are then demonstrating your ability to work in that very different environment to the more traditional academic subjects.